# editing tag.string property with BeautifulSoup (bs4) to string including markup

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, beautifulsoup

I have an html document that I wish to edit such that any word(s) within it can be highlighted/made bold.

I have the html in memory and have passed to BeautifulSoup. I iteratate through all tags and take their string elements. If any string contains a matching word, I edit the string and replace it into the html with markup wrapping around the desired word.

```
from flask import Flask, Markup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def match( documentText: str, searchQuery: str) -> Markup:
    words = documentText.split( ' ')
    if len( words) >= 3:
        words[2] = f'<strong>{ words[2]}</strong>'
        logger.info( f'{ words=}')

    return Markup( ' '.join( words))

for link in html.find_all( True):
    if ( link.string):
        link.string = match( link.string, searchQuery)

app = Flask( __name__)

@app.route( '/')
def home():
    logger.info( 'trying markup and testing logging') 
    return str( html), 200

app.run( debug=True)
```

Now, instead of rendering a page with bold words where I would like them, I visually see the html tags, this is because if I view source, the tags are actually represented by `&gt;`. This would appear to be coming from the line "link.string = match( link.string, searchQuery)" - which I guess could well make sense, in that BeautifulSoup is doing type checking and ensuring the only thing that goes in the tag.string field is indeed a string. The ideal end state I guess then would be to make a branch off the tag to include a  child tag.

Is this a problem anybody else has previously solved? My solution to this whole thing seems chunky and inelegant so I wouldn't mind a better route if anybody has one.

Comment: What about just calling ```return str(html).replace("&gt;",">").replace("&lt","<"), 200```?

Comment: @Kristian Yes, that will do it. Thanks! It's been one of those days...

Comment: I have updated my answer to show a better approach

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, just replace back those html special characters with str.replace()

```
from flask import Flask, Markup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# ...
@app.route( '/')
def home():
    logger.info( 'trying markup and testing logging') 
    return str(html).replace("&gt;",">").replace("&lt","<"), 200

app.run( debug=True)
```

Be careful since html special characters is not just `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Html special characters reference: https://www.html.am/reference/html-special-characters.cfm

#### Better Approach:

This approach will change all html special chars back to it's un-escapced form

```
import html.parser
htmlparser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
html_decoded_string = parser.unescape(str(html))
return html_decoded_string , 200
```

do note that on Python 2, the import statement (module name) might be a little bit different